# Django S3 : UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, utf-8, byte

I'm trying to use s3 to fetch images on my website.

I'm trying to use get_object() to access to the image object.

The part of the object that I want to return is the Body, which type is StreamingBody.
I want to convert the StreamingBody into string to return it.

Here is my code :

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_image(request, image):
    """Get image link"""
    key = "media/" + str(image)
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4', region_name=settings.AWS_S3_REGION_NAME))
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, Key=key)
    
    return Response(obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from store import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('images/<str:image>', views.get_image),
]
```

`obj['Body'].read()` return bytes that I'm tring to decode in utf-8.

When I run `obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')`, I get this error : **UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte**

Thank you by advance for your help

**UPDATE**

I had to return the image data as an HttpResponse and without encoding :

```
image_data = obj['Body'].read()    
return HttpResponse(image_data, content_type="image/jpeg")
```

Comment: If it's an image it's most likely binary data not text. Is this method supposed to return the image data or a link to the image?

Comment: @IainShelvington I'm trying to return the image data

Comment: What's the data going to be used for? I don't think you need the call to `.decode` anyway

Comment: @IainShelvington I need to create an endpoint that serves images. If I don't call ```.decode``` I get this error : ```'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'```

Comment: I think whatever is calling that function is expecting a file-like object to be returned since it's looking for "read", perhaps you just need to return `return obj['Body']`

Comment: When I try to return only ```obj['Body']``` I get the same error as at the beginning

Comment: Can you share the code that calls this function?

Comment: @IainShelvington I edited my post

Comment: BTW why are you even downloading the image if you just want to serve it to the user? You can make a [presigned url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) and give it to the user to download themselves.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what exactly you want to do:

#### Display the image:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view


@api_view(['GET'])
def get_image(request, image):
    ...
    
    data = obj['Body'].read()

    return HttpResponse(data, content_type=obj["ContentType"])
```

#### Display `base64` [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

```
import base64

from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view


@api_view(['GET'])
def get_image(request, image):
    ...
    
    data = obj['Body'].read()
    base64_data = base64.b64encode(data).decode("utf-8")

    return HttpResponse(f'<img src="data:{obj["ContentType"]};base64,{base64_data}">')
```

It looks like you're using [Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) so if you want to return JSON then you'll have to encode it using `base64` for instance:

```
import base64

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response


@api_view(['GET'])
def get_image(request, image):
    ...
    
    data = obj['Body'].read()
    base64_data = base64.b64encode(data).decode("utf-8")

    return Response(base64_data)
```